# effeminare = evirare (?)

Tags: verbs, morphology, derivation

Assuming that (i) the meanings of *vir* and *femina* are indeed opposite and (ii) the meaning of the prefix *ex-* is quite transparent, why are the verbs [*evirare*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eviro) and [*effeminare*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/effemino) then synonymous? Are there further similar pairs/examples of verbs in Latin?

NB: one could say that these two verbs are not really synonymous. Properly speaking, *evirare* means 'to deprive of manhood' and *effeminare* means 'to make feminine'. Fine, but why does *evirare* not mean 'to make masculine'? Here I'm interested in how semantics/meaning is related to the morphological structure.

Comment: I wonder if the duplication of the -f- in *effemino* isn't perhaps a hint to a different etymology, namely that it is derived from *ad* + *femina* (i.e. via **affemino*)?

Comment: @gmvh I don't think so but it is interesting to point out that both _*affeminare_ and _effeminare_ can be posited in order to explain Spanish "afeminar" and Catalan "efeminar", respectively. Note that the source prefix _ex-_ involved in _effeminare_ is the same one involved in _**ef**ferare_ (cf. Cat. "fer (algú) **sortir** ferotge"; 'to make (someone) to become fierce'). The prefix _ad-_ is not involved in their formation.

Answer (score 6):

The praefix *ex/e/ec-* has an 'original' meaning of "out, away" (*emitto, evanesco*), which also developed into a more general idea of privation or even negation, like "un-" (*exonero*).

Another later sense is "throughout, to the end", which additionally developed into "thoroughly, completely" (*evinco, enarro*) in turn.

I suspect *eviro* "to unman" has the sense of privation, like *emasculo* "to unman"; but it is not entirely clear in which sense the praefix was used to form *effemino*.

None of the dictionaries I consulted seem to provide conclusive evidence. I think it may have been the sense of "thoroughly, completely", resulting in "to become utterly feminine".

Alternatively, it may have been formed by some sort of inverted (sloppy?) analogy with *eviro* and *emasculo*. It would be an odd analogy, almost the opposite of those verbs, but etymology works in strange ways.

[Lewis & Short](http://archimedes.fas.harvard.edu/cgi-bin/dict?name=ls&lang=la&word=ex&filter=CUTF8) suggest *ec-* in *effemino* has the sense "out of (a former nature)", but I find their reasoning somewhat inconsistent:

> Primarily and most freq. of place, *out* or *forth*: exeo, elabor, educo, evado, etc.; and in an upward direction: emineo, effervesco, effero, erigo, exsurgo, exsulto, extollo, everto, etc.—
>
> Hence also, trop., *out of (a former nature)*, as in effeminare, qs. to change out of his own nature into that of a woman: effero, are, to render wild; thus ex comes to denote privation or negation, Engl. un-: exanimare, excusare, enodare, exonerare, effrenare, egelidus, I., elinguis, elumbis, etc.—

While *effero (efferare)*, "to make wild", works in the same direction as *effemino*, their other examples do not: *exanimare* does not mean "to deprive someone out of his nature into an anima", but rather "to deprive someone of his anima". The root word is the thing one is deprived of, not the thing one is turned into.

Both *effero* and *effemino* could be explained based on the sense "thoroughly, completely".

The Oxford Latin Dictionary doesn't tell us much about any of this. De Vaan doesn't mention *effemino* nor *effero*, nor yet this specific sense of *ex/e/ec*, under neither *femina* nor *ferus*, nor yet under *ex/e/ec*, so he probably doesn't have any specific information either.

Comment: Many thanks for your interesting answer. I'm not convinced by your proposal that the prefix of the verb _effeminare_ has an intensive meaning ('thoroughly/completely'). Rather my intuition is that the prefix here maintains its original meaning (it expresses a source). In my opinion, the paraphrase put forward by Lewis & Short is very appropriate: 'to change **out** of his own nature into that of a woman'. It seems that the nominal root of _evirare_ specifies the source (_vir_) but not the goal, whereas the root of _effeminare_ specifies the goal (_femina_) but not the source.

Comment: @Mitomino: Don't you think it's odd how a verb with *ec-* should specify the goal as its direct object? None of the other verbs do this, with the possible exception of *effero*. Why not simply *femino* instead? That would already mean "to change into a woman" without the praefix. So what does it really add?

Comment: In Catalan (and in other Romance languages) the verb _sortir_ (lit. 'to exit/to go-out') can be used to express change of state without mentioning the source (which is implicit): e.g., cf. the satellite-framed Lat. _**ef**ferare_ with the verb-framed transl. in Cat. 'fer **sortir** ferotge': i.e., 'to cause someone to become (lit. go-out) fierce'. Cf. also Cat. _**es**tovar_ (< ex- tou ('mollis')), i.e., 'fer **sortir** tou'.  Note also that in Latin there are motion verbs with a source prefix (e.g. _e(x)_-) that can be followed only by a goal PP (e.g. ad/in +NP), the source being implicit.

Comment: As for your invented denominal verb _feminare_, my intuition is that it would mean something like 'to provide X with _femina/feminis_', i.e., it would be a locatum verb. Cf. https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/13310/are-there-unprefixed-location-verbs-in-latin  By the way, you mention the verb _exanimare_ in your answer. Note that this verb is ambiguous: it can have a (dis)locatum reading (cf. also _exoculare_: the nominal root is the Figure) or a (dis)locatio reading (cf. also _eliminare_: the root is the Ground). In contrast, as predicted, _animare_ can only have the locatum reading.

Comment: @Mitomino Do you have a specific comparison to your derivation of *effeminare*?

Comment: This quote from Gibert-Sotelo (2017:325) can be a bit illuminating: "Brachet (2000) concludes that the primitive function of the prefix was that of introducing a complement specifying the initial state of a change of state event, an initial state that happens to be the opposite state of that expressed by the (“adjectival”) root and that corresponds to an inherent condition of the entity undergoing change (which is that of being masculine in the case of _effemino_ ‘to make feminine’, that of being bitter in the case of _edulco_ ‘to sweeten’,...)". https://www.tdx.cat/handle/10803/461414#page=1

Comment: @cmw The Catalan paraphrase with the transitive causative verb _fer_ ('make') plus the unaccusative change verb **_sortir_** ('to go **out**'/'to **ex**it') corresponding to Lat. _**ef**feminare_ is a bit stilted but is possible/understandable: 'fer (algú) sortir dona/femella' (i.e.,'to cause someone to become (lit. to go-out) woman'). NB: it is true that the Cat. paraphrase 'fer sortir ferotge' (cf. Lat. _efferare_) sounds better, i.e., with adjectival predicates.

Comment: @cmw The relevant reference/monograph mentioned by Gibert-Sotelo (2017) is the following one, which, unfortunately, I don't have at my disposal now. Brachet, Jean-Paul (2000). _Recherches sur les préverbes_ de- _et_ ex- _du latin_. Bruxelles: Latomus.

Comment: @mitomino Yes, I understand what you were saying better now. I don't think the Catalan is necessary here, *edulco* should suffice, though I don't see it in Lewis and Short and don't have the OLD at home. But it makes sense that the *ex* is referring to the direct object after the verb: *virum effeminare* -> to bring the woman out of the man, almost a shorthand (forgot the linguistic term for this construction) for *\*feminare ex viro*.

Answer (score -1):

Here's my initial takeaway:

According to the Wiktionary links you included, *evirare* is a contraction of *ex-virare*, so something like "to take out of a man". In Greek (maybe sometimes in Latin too), this use of *ex-* (Greek *εξ-*) would take the genitive as a genitive of separation (as in "he came out of the woods, he walked out of the house" in English). From what I've encountered, this use is usually soaked up by the ablative case in Latin which Greek does not have.

Neither in Wiktionary nor in Lewis and Short is *effeminare* described as a contraction with *ex-*. For now, I assume it's just a simple verb-ization of *feminare* with the *e* maybe a vocal affect (I'm thinking of Spanish "espiritu" from *spiritu*, or "estar" from *stare*).

If we do take *effeminare* to be a contraction with *ex-*, it would be comparable to the Greek genitive of accompaniment, which, despite using the same case and form, does hold the opposite meaning. We do this in modern English too: "out of curiosity" would probably be more sensible as "in curiosity", "out of sheer force of will" as "in sheer force of will". Meanwhile, the word "out" holds perhaps an opposite meaning in phrases such as "out of line" or "out of order". Particularly in the second phrase, "out" holds the opposite meaning to "in", but "out of curiosity" and "in curiosity" are synonyms.

The other classical language example I can think of where a prefix/preposition can hold opposite meanings is the distinction between the Greek alpha privative and the copulative alpha. Both consist of the prefix *α-*, but while the alpha privative negates the following word (think modern English "atypical", "asexual", "apolitical"), the copulative expresses sameness as in the Greek word for brother, *αδελφος*, meaning literally "of the same womb".

In summary, I don't think *effeminare* is a contraction with *ex-*. But if it is, that's okay, because *ex* can have either an inclusive or an exclusive meaning.

Comment: Spanish _estar_ etc come from a phonological change: Latin allowed certain types of initial consonant clusters, but Western Romance didn't, so a vowel got attached to remedy that. But Latin had no issue with initial _f_, as seen in the word _femina_ itself.

Comment: @Draconis that's a pretty good point. So do you think *effeminare* does come from *ex-*? It very well could.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Isidoritas! The last point about *ex-* having both inclusive and exclusive meaning is very interesting. Can you expand upon it with an example of both?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Sure! I'm looking on the Lewis and Short page for the preposition *ex* (rather than the prefix, but I think their commentary still applies). Both of these uses would be encompassed under their third definition:

"III: In other relations, and in gen. where a going out or forth, a coming or springing out of any thing is conceivable."


The inclusive *ex* is subdefintion C: "To indicate the material of which any thing is made or consists". The exclusive is subdefinition F: "To indicate a transition, i. e. a change, alteration, from one state or condition to another".

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta here's the link: http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=ex&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059

Comment: I fully agree with Joonas's comment above. Your last point, Isidoritas, seems to be very interesting. By the way, cf. the following information by the end of the link you've provided in your last comment above: "B. Signification. 1 (...) .—Hence also, trop., out of (a former nature), as in **_effeminare_, qs. to change out of his own nature into that of a woman**; _effero, are_, to render wild". So perhaps you would like to modify your answer above accordingly.

Comment: @Mitomino Jeez! That sure is embarrassing. Thank you for correcting me. What's your take on the role of *ex-* in this word (and in general)? By the way, when I was describing an "inclusive *ex-*", I was thinking of phrases like *ex animo*.