# Deriving verbs from nouns: iota > iotare

Tags: morphology

What is the natural way in which to derive verbs from nouns, where
their meaning is to furnish something with the thing named by the
noun?  For example, what might one call an omega furnished with an
iota subscriptum, if we wished to add only a participle; an omega
*iotatum*?  Or would this rather mean an omega *turned into* an iota?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are looking for a verb, I think your suggestion of *iotare* is actually a very good one. You observe that *iotare* might mean several other things(*) like *making a iota* or *becoming a iota*(in the passive (**)), which is apparently correct indeed, but that's how verbs work; they might mean different things and IMO we should not be deterred by this.

We can take the highely relevant example of the verb **corono** which is derived from the noun *corona* per [Wiktionry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/corono#Latin), it might mean several things, but among them the required meaning:

> **to furnish with a garland or crown**, to crown, wreathe (L&S dictionary)

(*) We might consider two examples: *corporo* (from corpus) and *radio* (from radius), it seems that *corporatus* is more of the meaning of "turned into a body"(as the active is rather to "form a body"), but with the case of *radiatus* the meaning is rather "shining" or "furnished with radia" (e.g. *corona radiata* white matter in the brain). But even *corporo* means according to L&S "to furnish with a body" which, as previously the body was not existing, is almost identical to *fashion into body*

(**) For the active meaning *to become a iota*, it can be argued that a better suggestion would be *iotabesco*, i.e using the suffix -sco, like *rubesco*.

---

But if we only need "participle" or adj. I second @Asteroides, just to add another example *manubriatus* (furnished with a handle (manubrium)), where, again, it seems there is no verb; one may claim, as suggested in your comment, that those example are participles of defective verbs, but I find no problem with that as long as the meaning is clear.

Comment: Two remarks on your invented verb _iotabesco_. Note that _b_ is part of the root of the verb you mention next: _ru**b**esco_. Note also that unprefixed verbs formed with the suffix _-sco_ are typically atelic (i.e. they do not involve a culmination, whereby the typical paraphrase "to become X" is often not accurate, as pointed out by Haverling (2000, 2010)). The telic verbs with suffix _-sco_ are the ones that are prefixed. The authoritative reference on this subject is Haverling (2000), mentioned in  https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/8848/aret-aridus-est ).

Comment: As for why denominal verbs involving the so-called "locatum object" paraphrase 'to provide X with Noun' (e.g., _iotare_ as 'to provide X with _iota_'), are typically unprefixed, see https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/13310/are-there-unprefixed-location-verbs-in-latin

Comment: Finally, rather than saying that _manubriatus_ or _dentatus_ are "participles of defective verbs" (the label "defective verb" is misleading here, I think), it's better to say that they are "stative participles", which lack a verbal eventive layer (that's why these participles behave like "simple" adjectives). See my answer to Asteroides based on Embick's (2004) tripartite typology of participles (1) eventive passive // 2) resultative // 3) stative).

Comment: @Mitomino, thanks for your illustrative comments. I'll take care to read those links later on. Good catch with respect to my *iota**b**esco*, maybe *iotaesco* or *iotasco* just didn't sound well to me for some reason, or influenced as you imply by *rubesco*. It indeed feels like *iotasco* is too short. we find this *a*, also in other verbs like *labasco* (labo + sco), but I wonder if *ioto* + *sco* will work the same, since *ioto* is derived from iot**a**.

Comment: @Mitomino, I've just find *vesperasco* from *vespera*. so indeed *iotasco* is probably the correct choice.

Comment: @Mitomino, If you had to chose a prefix to make it a telic verb, what would it be? *ex*, *per*, something else ?

Comment: For the reasons mentioned above I think that the use of a  _-sco_ verb like _iotasco_ would not work here. If Haverling is right (and I think she is), this invented verb would mean an **ongoing** process (atelic reading) rather than 'to become a iota' (telic reading). According to her, note that _rubesco_ does not mean 'to become red' (telic reading) but rather 'to grow red' (atelic reading).

Comment: The use of prefixes with _-sco_ verbs is determined by the **aspectual phase** you want to focus on (e.g. _ad-_ and _in-_ for the initial/ingressive phase, _per_- for the medial/progressive phase and _ex-_ for the final/egressive one). All these options sound odd to me when applied to _iotare_.

Answer (score 5):

There is a suffix [-atus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-atus) that forms adjectives with this kind of meaning. Like English *-ed,* it looks the same as a common past participle ending, but the words are not actually past participles: no corresponding finite verb is necessarily in use.

For example, *[dentatus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=dentatus)* means “toothed” in the sense of “having teeth”; it is not a participle meaning “having been toothed”, and no Latin verb *dento, dentare* exists to my knowledge.

Comment: I don't see how you can infer from the fact that no other forms are in (recorded) use that they are not participles.  Noone speaks of toothing either, but it seems obvious (to me at least) that _toothed_ is a participle (of a highly ``defective'' verb).

Comment: @NullusMaximus As for your point "but it seems obvious (to me at least) that _toothed_ is a participle", note that Asteroides is not saying that _dentatus_ is not a participle. What s/he is saying is that "it is not a participle meaning 'having been toothed". In linguistic terms, what Asteroides is saying is that _dentatus_ is not an eventive passive participle. In Embick's (2004) terminology _dentatus_ is a **stative participle**, which has a clear adjectival behavior. Cf. https://www.ling.upenn.edu/~embick/result.pdf

Answer (score 2):

There is the Greek ending *-ιζω*, which is still productive in English as the ending *-ize/-ise*, and which one could certainly latinize into -izo (with a "foreign" letter Z), or into *-iso* or *-ico*. Of course, most of the verbs you'd derive in that way would be neologisms.

Comment: I was wondering to what extent verbs with the suffix _-izo_ can have the so-called "locatum object" paraphrase mentioned by the OP above ('to furnish something with the thing named by the noun'). It seems to me that the verbs you mention do not form "locatum verbs" (i.e. 'to furnish something with X') but rather change of state verbs where the noun is expressing the final state (i.e. 'to make something to be converted into X'). Finally, it is perhaps worth pointing out that this suffix forms Result verbs from Late Latin onwards (NB: in Early and Classical Latin this suffix formed Manner verbs)